# IE - input box goes down 1px on focus

Tags: css, internet-explorer

as described in the subject - in Internet Explorer 11 (I don't know how it goes with earlier versions) my input boxes go around 1px down on focus.

I've applied:

```
textarea:focus, input:focus{
  outline: 0 !important;
}
```

and I don't have the blue outline anymore, however the problem with 1px down still exists.

Any idea what's causing it?

Comment: Most likely a `border`, `padding`, `margin` or `top` style applied to `:focus` but not to the element itself, or vice versa. Check the rest of your styles to see if there's any styles like those I mentioned.

Comment: Have you tried setting `z-index` property?

Comment: @Joeytje50 - I don't see any styles of such kind applied to the element (checking in developer tools). I set border, padding, margin and top to 0 and no change.

Pritam - I followed your advice and set position:relative, z-index:1000000, without success.

Comment: Could you link us to some kind of demo? Otherwise we won't be able to help you. These suggestions are just guesses, but if that doesn't work, we can't really help you.

Comment: I tried creating a fiddle, but everything works well there. It's got to be something I added on the way.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, found the answer - it seems like I set a line-height higher than the input box somewhere along the way.